# Twilio Outbound POST: Content-Type on Text

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, servicenow

My goal is to take a text message sent to Twilio #, POST that information to my platform (ServiceNow). I believe my issue is that ServiceNow Script API can only receive content-type = [application/json, application/xml, text/xml] and so I get an error response invalid content type.

Looking at Twilio  debugger, I don't see any explicit parameter called content-type. Any insights on what I might do here?

[image]

```
Response:
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid content-type. Supported request media types for this service are: [application/json, application/xml, text/xml]",
        "detail": null
    },
    "status": "failure"
}
```

Comment: Content-type is an http header and I'm not sure if that is shown in the debugger

Comment: I'm guessing this is a REST call to ServiceNow. Enable REST debugging by setting the system property `glide.rest.debug` to `true` and see if it gives you any insight. <https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/jakarta-servicenow-platform/page/integrate/inbound-rest/reference/r_DebuggingRESTQueries.html>

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When [Twilio sends a webhook for an incoming message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request) the request is formatted as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

If you are unable to find a way for ServiceNow to accept `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you could try using a [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/runtime/functions) to translate the data to JSON and send it on to your endpoint.

Let me know if that helps at all.